# Mechanism Design with Quantal Best Response

Tags: microeconomics, game-theory, behavioral-economics, mechanism-design

I was wondering if there is a sensible definition of mechanism design (incentive compatibility and individual rationality) when the agent (bidder) is only boundedly rational. In the classical mechanism design theory, the bidder is fully rational, then incentive compatibility means that the allocation satisfies the property that the bidder's optimal strategy is to report truthfully. I saw a recent paper relaxes this constraint by allowing IC to be violated by $\epsilon$. See ``Mechanism Design under
Approximate Incentive Compatibility'' https://arxiv.org/pdf/2103.03403.pdf Is it possible to consider a maybe Bayesian framework where the bidder responds according to a quantal response function?